# Vim Join opened Html tags to same line

Tags: html, vim, code-snippets

So I've started using snippets with vim, now sometimes I like the closing tag to be put on a newline but other times I like the closing tag to be on the same line.

After typing a html tag and pressing the autocomplete key it's formatted as shown below, with the cursor position shown by the caret symbol

```
<td>
    ^
</td>
```

Currently, if I want both tags on the same line I have to move the cursor up a line and repeatedly hit Shift+J to join the lines, but this takes multiple key strokes

Is there a fast way (without moving the cursor from it's current position), to join the two lines together to look like, from the above code snippet

```
<td>^</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Vim's built-in *inner tag* text object to delete (`dit`) or change (`cit`) the whitespace / text inside the tags. (This assumes the tags are indented; without indent, you still need a `J` to join the end tag to the current line.)

Comment: the dit and cit commands are exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Comment: @Fractale: `J` is a standalone command, on its own, whereas `d` and `c` both are followed by a `{motion}` (here: the `it` "inner tag" text object). `Jit` is interpreted by Vim as _join_, _enter insert mode_, _type literal t_.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat how to then join line between two html tag?

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
:.,/td>/j
```

meaning from the current line (`.`) to (`,`) search for "td>" (`/td>/`) join the lines (`j`)